# Reducing image size before pasting into Word

Tags: image, resize, digital, irfanview

I have images taken with my phone. If I paste them into Word, they're huge! If I resize them with Irfanview before pasting into Word, the quality is poor. If I resize the image in Word by dragging its corners, it's fine. I'm obviously missing something in my understanding of digital image technology, but I don't know what it is!

Comment: There may be a more scientific way, but you could make a 200x200 pixel solid red image with MS-Paint, or Photoshop or Irfanview and insert it into Word without resizing and print it. If it fills 1/4 of the page width, that means you need 800 pixel wide images. So you can resize your phone camera pictures to be 800 pixels wide in Irfanview. As an aside, if your phone camera is 12 megapixels that's 4,000x3,000 which means your images are 5x wider and 5x taller than necessary and therefore 25x too big....

Comment: Note the above is a simplistic comment, not a well-researched answer. Maybe read here... https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010218_Best_Quality_for_High_Resolution_Graphics.html